# How to add input from textarea tag in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have been trying to fetch input from textarea tag in Django but its not working.

this my form

```
<form method="POST" action="/" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="4"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Post comment</button>
</form>
```

this is my view

```
if request.method=='POST':
    username = request.user
    comment = request.POST.get('comment')
    new_comment = Pcomments(username=username,comment=comment,
        date = datetime.date.today())
    new_comment.save()
```

Comment: "its not working". What specifically is not working? Are there errors? Please provide some debugging to help users answer your question

Comment: the comment is not getting added to the database.

Comment: my guess is that you're sending the form to the wrong url ('ie . `<form action="/">`) but the view you're showing is connected to different URL. But again as @rob said - not enough information to be sure.

Comment: please put error traceback in question